# U.S. Electrical: How can I supply a 250v 10A 3-wire grounded outlet from nearby 4-wire 250v stove/range outlet?

Tags: electrical

U.S. Electrical: How can I supply a 250v 10A 3-wire grounded outlet from nearby 4-wire 250v stove/range outlet?

Many thanks for your thoughts....

Comment: That seems like an odd combination. What type of device are you going to plug into this outlet? Does it not need ground? (which would generally be a safety issue, meaning it should probably actually be a 4-wire outlet with the appliance cord changed to match) Or does it not need neutral?

Comment: Yes please tell us about the device/appliance.  Providing make and model numbers, and or a well lit picture of the devices plug looking straight down on it.  Or if the NEMA connector number is known that also explains more.

Comment: The reference to a 10A outlet makes me think you're trying to power a European device in the US.  Is that the case? If so, what sort of thing is it?

Comment: This sounds like an odd question - you are trying to add to that existing circuit. You can't do that legally as that Stove Range circuit is required by code to be a dedicated circuit. So if you are trying to put the outlets in parallel (an inline run) you can't legally do that. Now if you run another circuit / line from your circuit breaker panel you can do that.

Comment: @Philip, what kind of 3 wire outlet do you need?  As far as I know, there are no 250V 3-wire grounded outlets in the US.  Are you trying to plug in a stove that has a 3 prong plug?  If so, you simply need to replace the stove's cord with a 4 prong version and you can use the existing outlet.

Comment: Will the stove outlet also be used for the stove?  Or can you convert it to a different outlet for this new 10 amp *thing* you want to hook up?  Also if it’s a no neutral situation do you have another 15 or 20 amp circuit feeding a single kitchen counter outlet?  Maybe that could be converted instead.

Comment: @mrog -- the outlet you're saying doesn't exist is called a NEMA 6-15R, by the way...

Comment: @Philip you need to clarify what exactly you are desiring to do. Connect wires to the internals of your range outlet to feed a second receptacle to connect this 10A device to? Or ?? Create a corded interchange plug that you can plug into your range outlet in order to plug in this other device ? Perhaps it is a European cook top ? Provide more information ..so you get the right and the safe answers - not to mention with in legal code rules to do what you desire.

Comment: Im in the U.S. & want to use a 240v electric kettle (UK 13-A 3-Pin plug to be  replaced with NEMA-standard plug (Leviton 5666-CA 15A 250v Straight Blade, Industrial Grade, Grounding) and replace existing 20A 110v Decora single-gang outlet with decora-style NEMA Hubbell RRD155BK15A 250V outlet that fits nicely into existing recessed box in the backsplash.  I would like to supply this outlet from a 4-pin 2-phase 250v AC stove outlet 3' away.  What guage should the supply wire be? Is there any way to ensure that I have a true ground (earth) in addition to the neutral?  Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks for pointing out the NEMA 6-15 to me. I haven't seen one before.

Comment: Is the *existing* 110V outlet on its own homerun, or does it share a circuit with other outlets?

Comment: To ThreePhaseEEl:  Existing outlet is wired to a 110v 20-A GFCI-protected circuit (there is also a 2nd 110v 20A GFCI circuit a few yards away in this kitchen but the circuit-breakers for both circuits are attached to the same bus on the panel.

Comment: From the many comments (thanks!), it seems the safest thing to do might to use the existing UK plug (which has its own replaceable 13-A rated fuse) and, upside-down, under kitchen cabinet, install a UK receptable for this electrical kettle -something I wanted to avoid but would solve the issue of a 15-A appliance a 4-A stove circuit without GFCI (I can't find a suitable GFCI).

Answer (score 1):

In the US, a 230/240V 10A device would use a NEMA 6-15 plug.  It would plug into a 6-15 or 6-20 receptacle.  You may notice a family resemblance.

[image]

Your 4-wire range receptacle is surely a NEMA 14-50 receptacle. This contains all the conductors a NEMA 6 would require, but it would not have the correct value of fuse/circuit breaker so it would not safely protect the 10A appliance from faults.

For a one- time special use such as running a floor sander, an adapter cable can be used.

If this is to be a regular tool in your kitchen, a circuit must be used that has a 2-pole, 15A or 20A breaker and NEMA 6 or 14 receptacle sizes appropriate to the breaker. The wire size must also match the breaker, but it is allowed to be oversized, so the heavy range wiring could be re-tasked for this purpose.  And then further, the breaker must be GFCI type.

"But wait, most GFCIs that I see in homes are the kind that are built into a receptacle, instead of the much more expensive GFCI breaker.  Can't I use a GFCI receptacle instead?"  Sure, if you can find a GFCI NEMA 6 receptcle.   I doubt you can, though.

Comment: if he is going to use his Range outlet as the power for this device he would be fine - but from his question and info it reads like op wants to piggy back another receptacle on a range outlet which makes the circuit no longer dedicated and therefore violates NEC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that legally as that Stove Range circuit is required by code to be a dedicated circuit. So if you are trying to put the outlets in parallel (an inline run) you can't legally do that. Now if you run another circuit / line from your circuit breaker panel you can do that.

Comment: This answer is probably incomplete because it’s pre-mature.  Until we know further details from the OP it’s impossible to tell what he can or can’t do, your answer does inspire my next question above tho.

Comment: @Tyson - your question above is appropriate. However since the op did not specify he was going to remove that stove/range receptacle - I did assume he was thinking to use both . Although he could leave the stove/range receptacle "unplugged", the circuit wiring would still violate code as it would not be a dedicated circuit.

Comment: Depends what it is he’s trying/wants to do.  For example: If it’s a portable kiln for occasional use, one could attach a fused disconnect to the portable kiln and use a 50amp cord.  There is not enough information present at this time to answer this question without assumptions.

Comment: @Tyson a dedicated circuit means dedicated - nothing else connected. Even if it has a disconnect or is Fused (connected means at anytime) - it still cannot be connected, that is National Electrical Code. There is a small exception in Article 220 of the NEC to permit a counter-top cooking unit and not more than two wall-mounted ovens to be treated as a single range and connected to the same circuit. That is your exception to the rule.

Comment: @Ken -- The issue with a multi-outlet branch 50A branch circuit has nothing to do with Art 220 at all; instead, 210.23(C) restricts multi-outlet 40/50A branch circuits in dwelling units to fixed cooking units.  (Interestingly enough, a 60A multioutlet branch circuit has no such limitation, it simply can't ever supply a lighting load)